# Many-to-many multiple tables design

Tags: database-design

I'm planning a design for courser.
A user can take a course, and a course will contain multiple goals and multiple subgoals. (these goals are the same but depending on the course it will be a "complete" goal or just a subgoal)

[image: Database design]

Will this be a "good" design, or should I rethink?

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to search and normalize, you could do:

```
Course
  CourseID
  Name

Goal
  GoalID
  Name

GoalType
  TypeID
  Value        <-- can be goal or sub-goal

Course-Goal
  CourseID
  GoalID
  GoalTypeID
```

This way you will only have to query one table (Course-Goal).  Tables should be related to objects in your requirements.  Tables should not express types or criteria.